# Select Where In - for all line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an extra information to catch about my users, the sitecode associate.

To do that, I use a request with a `WHERE IN` construction.

But I have sometimes the same value in the `IN` clause, and I need to show the data for each line (my request return the result only once.)

Here is my request :

```
SELECT [SiteCode]
FROM [Configuration].[Site]
  INNER JOIN [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur]
    ON [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur].[SiteDefaultId] = [Configuration].[Site].[SiteId]
WHERE [Login] IN ('XXXXXXXX', 'YYYYYY', 'YYYYYY', 'YYYYYY',)
```

This request return only two result, and I need to return 4 results (3 will be be the same).

Here is the result :

```
SiteCode
0002153
0005963
```

And here is what I need for my example :

```
SiteCode
0002153
0005963
0005963
0005963
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the product by joining the criterias

```
SELECT [SiteCode]
FROM [Configuration].[Site]
  INNER JOIN [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur]
    ON [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur].[SiteDefaultId] = [Configuration].[Site].[SiteId]
  INNER JOIN (VALUES('XXXXXXXX'), ('YYYYYY'), ('YYYYYY'), ('YYYYYY')) cri(Login) ON [Login] = cri.Login
```

Comment: Working ! Thanks.
I have a last point, my data are sorted in a different order than the one I give them. For example I have result like that : `sitecode
BBBBBB
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
BBBBBB`, do you know how to order them in the order of the copy/paste ?

Comment: Assume you preserve the order when insert to the criteria table, and that table can add a identity column, finally you order the result by that identity column.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `DISTINCT` to keep duplicates...

```
SELECT [SiteCode], [Login]
FROM [Configuration].[Site]
  INNER JOIN [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur]
    ON [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur].[SiteDefaultId] = [Configuration].[Site].[SiteId]
WHERE [Login] IN ('XXXXXXXX', 'YYYYYY', 'YYYYYY', 'YYYYYY',)
```

**EDIT:**

To return the same row several times, you can't do a simple `JOIN` with an `IN`, you need to do a `UNION ALL` with one `SELECT` for each value:

```
SELECT [SiteCode], [Login]
FROM [Configuration].[Site]
  INNER JOIN [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur]
    ON [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur].[SiteDefaultId] = [Configuration].[Site].[SiteId]
WHERE [Login] = 'XXXXXXXX'
UNION ALL
SELECT [SiteCode], [Login]
FROM [Configuration].[Site]
  INNER JOIN [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur]
    ON [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur].[SiteDefaultId] = [Configuration].[Site].[SiteId]
WHERE [Login] = 'YYYYYY'
UNION ALL
SELECT [SiteCode], [Login]
FROM [Configuration].[Site]
  INNER JOIN [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur]
    ON [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur].[SiteDefaultId] = [Configuration].[Site].[SiteId]
WHERE [Login] = 'YYYYYY'
UNION ALL
SELECT [SiteCode], [Login]
FROM [Configuration].[Site]
  INNER JOIN [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur]
    ON [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur].[SiteDefaultId] = [Configuration].[Site].[SiteId]
WHERE [Login] = 'YYYYYY'
```

Comment: Does three different YYYYYY exist in you table?

Comment: No, there is only one value, but I need to display the information three time.

Comment: I doesn't explain correctly my situation. I edit my post

Answer (score 1):

The only idea i have for that problem is that you create a new table with only one column and the values 'XXXXXXXX', 'YYYYYY', 'YYYYYY', 'YYYYYY'.

Then you can do an inner join on that table and it will return the 'YYYYYY' data three times.

```
SELECT [SiteCode], [Login]
FROM [Configuration].[Site]
  INNER JOIN [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur]
    ON [Utilisateur].[Utilisateur].[SiteDefaultId] = [Configuration].[Site].[SiteId] INNER JOIN tempTbl ON [Configuration].[Site].[Login] = tempTbl.Login
```